# When do I put the variable into the parenthesis of a .open() and when do i put it in front of the .open()

Tags: python-2.7

```
1 from sys import argv
2 from os.path import exists
3
4 script, from_file, to_file = argv
5
6 print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)
7
8 # we could do these two on one line too, how?
9 input = open(from_file)
10 indata = input.read()
11
12 print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)
13
14 print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
15 print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."
16 raw_input()
17
18 output = open(to_file, 'w')
19 output.write(indata)
20
21 print "Alright, all done."
22
23 output.close()
24 input.close()
```

Im not sure what the rule difference is between something like line 19 where there is a variable before the period and also within the parenthesis. I'm a beginner and would like to  clarify this because I tried to write some code and was confused about this point...

Answer (score 0):

This means you're calling a method of an object. Let's look at line 18:

```
output = open(to_file, 'w')
```

This returns a file object and assigns it to the variable `output`. You can now call methods of a file object (such as `output.read()` to read the file's contents). Similarly, you can use `output.write(...)` to write data to the file:

```
output.write(indata)
```

The above line means: write the contents of `indata` to the file object `output`. You're correct that there are two variables involved in this operation.

Comment: But if I opened the file in write mode, as in the first example that you provided, can I still output.read() the file without emptying the contents? Because I know that write mode will clear the contents of the file if I don't write anything within it...